# Adblock Plus is blocking my custom Facebook feed's images

Tags: javascript, php, image, facebook-graph-api, adblock

I am using Facebook's graph API to pull images posted to a company FB page and putting them on a web page. Some images show up fine, some don't show up at all. Looking at the page's source code I can see that all the images that are working have a URL that begins: graph.facebook.com/... and the images that won't load begin with: facebook.com/ads/images/...

Suspecting that the /ads/ part of the URL was triggering Adblock to block the images, I disabled Adblock for the page and the missing images appeared.

Given that is impractical to expect all visitors not to use Adblock, I'm wondering how I can fix this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought...  But it might be because Facebook is pulling those ads in from somewhere else.  Even if the URL says differently.  In any case, if you are jacking someone else's ad code for your page, you shouldn't be surprised when things don't work right.

Comment: The images served from the facebook.com/ads/... URL are not ads, which is the problem. I know they're using CDNs but this does not seem to affect the loading of images, instead this seems to be a problem with the /ads/ part of the URL triggering Adblock Plus.

Answer (score 0):

Its the way filters are implemented inside Adblock. For them, somehow the api and image along with the ip lookup translates to an ad which should be blocked. They use lot of parameters to determine if it translates to an ad or not like comparing image dimensions, filename, social media links, behaviour etc. So about the question of fixing it would simply would be to correct the way Adblock works or improving its detection for the ads in this case.